# How can I make a ios UIAlert that displays data taken from a text field in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

How can I make a native UIAlert display data taken from a text field. I can only find UIAlert that prompt to enter data and display in a label but nothing that displays from a text field.

I need to make A button when pressed get value from them and display the values like:
- Field 1: X
- Field 2: Y
in native popup.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlert is deprecated since iOS 9. Hope this helps:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uialertcontroller

http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/